# twemojis package can't be used, doesn't show up locally, AND can't be installed?

Tags: packages, missing

When you search CTAN `twemojis` package, you find it: https://ctan.org/pkg/twemojis.

---

When I try to use it, it says package not found.

```
\usepackage{twemojis}
```

```
! LaTeX Error: File `twemojis.sty' not found.
```

---

When I try to download it, it says package not found.

```
❯ tlmgr install twemojis
tlmgr: package repository https://ctan.asis.ai/systems/texlive/tlnet (verified)
tlmgr install: package twemojis not present in repository.
tlmgr: action install returned an error; continuing.
tlmgr: An error has occurred. See above messages. Exiting.
```

```
❯ tlmgr install --repository="https://gitlab.com/rossel.jost/latex-twemojis"

/Library/TeX/texbin/tlmgr: TLPDB::from_file could not initialize from: https://gitlab.com/rossel.jost/latex-twemojis/tlpkg/texlive.tlpdb
/Library/TeX/texbin/tlmgr: Maybe the repository setting should be changed.
/Library/TeX/texbin/tlmgr: More info: https://tug.org/texlive/acquire.html
```

---

What to do ?

Comment: Tlmgr will only install packages that are part of TeX Live. You will have to download it from CTAN and manually install it. If you need help with that let us know.

Comment: @HerbSchulz, yea actually, I might need some help.

Comment: I'm on MacOS. I downloaded the `.zip` package from CTAN. Then I extracted the zip file, and got a directory called `twemojis`. It contains a few files: `.dtx`, `.ins`, `.sty`,  the documentation as a `.pdf`, and some assets in a sub-directory. Now what ?

Comment: What is in the sub directory?

Comment: All the emojis as `.pdf` files

Comment: First just put the .sty file and the folder of pdf images in the same folder as your document.

Comment: I assume that worked?

Comment: Yes it worked, thank you !

Comment: If you wish to use it with other documents there is another place to put the sty and folder where it will be found.

Comment: Where would that be @HerbSchulz ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create the `texmf/tex/latex/twemojis` in `~/Library`; i.e, create a `texmf` folder in `~/Library` then a `tex` folder inside the `~/Library/texmf` folder, etc. To open `~/Library`, the Library folder in your HOME folder, the `Go->Library (Shift-Cmd-L)` may be there. If not, click on the Go Menu and press and hold the `Option` key to make that menu item appear.

Place the .sty and folder of images inside the `~/Library/texmf/tex/latex/twemojis` folder.

That's it.

Comment: Thank you for your patience, this was very helpful.